# Android ScrollView not scrolling in Activity with Drawer Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, navigation-drawer, android-scrollview, drawerlayout

Let me introduce you to my activity:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_actionbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar_default"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar_actionbar"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar_actionbar">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        <!-- android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"-->
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragment_drawer"
            android:name="com.package.name.navigationdrawer.NavigationDrawerFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"/>
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

FrameLayout **main_fragment_container** is where I load different fragments depending on Navigation Drawer selections but when I load a fragment with a ScrollView scroll does not work, I can see the scrollbar when the fragment is loaded indicating that only a small section is on screen at the moment but it will never scroll. I tried some suggestions that mentioned encasing the ScrollView inside a LinearLayout, it made no difference.

I suspect the navigation drawer is "intercepting" the events which should reach the ScrollView but I'm lost as to what to do. This is the fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/fragment_who_scrollview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:src="@drawable/header_pic_s"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="17sp"
                android:text="TEEEEEST"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="20dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="17sp"
                android:text="TEEEEEST"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="20dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="17sp"
                android:text="TEEEEEST"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="20dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="17sp"
                android:text="TEEEEEST"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="20dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="17sp"
                android:text="TEEEEEST"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="20dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="17sp"
                android:text="TEEEEEST"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="20dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="17sp"
                android:text="TEEEEEST"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="20dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="17sp"
                android:text="TEEEEEST"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="20dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="17sp"
                android:text="TEEEEEST"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="20dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="17sp"
                android:text="TEEEEEST"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="20dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="17sp"
                android:text="TEEEEEST"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="20dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="17sp"
                android:text="TEEEEEST"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="20dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="17sp"
                android:text="TEEEEEST"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="20dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="17sp"
                android:text="TEEEEEST"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="20dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks for your time.

**UPDATE - LET ME ADD SOME ADDITIONAL INFO:**

- The problem here is not the ScrollView per se but the fact that in my activity layout the DrawerLayout is 'above' the ScrollView preventing any touch events reaching the ScrollView. If I remove the DrawerLayout the ScrollView scrolls JUST FINE.
- Similarly if I put ScrollView after DrawerLayout in activity layout the scroll works alright in the ScrollView but of course the DrawerLayout does not work as intended since it must be on top of everything else.

I hope I explained myself properly, by testing I'm sure of what the problem is but I'm not sure on how to fix it, my experience with Navigation Drawer is limited and I have no idea how to let the scroll event pass to the ScrollView instead of having the DrawerLayout intercept it.

Comment: This does not solve your problem, but you do not need the parent linearlayout around your scrollview. Your scrollview should act as main view.

Comment: Thanks, it is completely unnecessary indeed and I just removed it. I only tried it because it was given as an answer here when having scrolling problems with ScrollViews.

Comment: No prob :) Why is your framelayout (container) clickable? Is this where you add your content? Try removing this flag.

Comment: That FrameLayout is not where I load my fragments. The FrameLayout 'container' is part of the NavigationDrawer and that part works wonderfully. It is the FrameLayout 'main_fragment_container' that will be replaced in this case by a non scrollable ScrollView.

Comment: I added some additional info to the question.

Comment: Ah ok. I think all elements should be within your DrawerLayout, this should be the root of all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should move the framelayout with id "main_fragment_container" inside drawerlayout like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<include
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_actionbar"
    layout="@layout/toolbar_default"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar_actionbar">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar_actionbar" />

    <!-- android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"-->
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
        android:name="vodafone.navdrawertest.NavigationDrawerFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: I will give this as the correct answer. I also replied to my question with this solution (which works). Thanks! (especially to Thomas for helping me reach this solution myself)

Comment: I'd used this, but I can't still scroll down my drawer. Is it necessary to have a RelativeLayout before the DrawerLayout?

Answer (score 0):

Try reorder of your layout:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
android:id="@+id/drawer"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent“>

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        orientation="vertical">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_actionbar"
            layout="@layout/toolbar_default"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</FrameLayout>

<!-- android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"-->
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment_drawer"
    android:name="com.ulusol.knowmyshop.navigationdrawer.NavigationDrawerFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks but this layout messes everything up structure-wise and gives me both NO scrolling and NO navigation drawer.

Comment: While I cannot give this as a correct solution this helped me fix my layout. My FrameLayout does indeed have to go inside the DrawerLayout to be scrollable.

Comment: I reordered it again. But I don't know how the 'container' comes in place. In the end, it helped to find you the right answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Thomas for guiding me to the answer.

The FrameLayout where the ScrollView goes must be inside the DrawerLayout **to be scrollable**. I also ditched the other container Layout because it was not being used. This is how the activity remains:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_actionbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar_default"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar_actionbar">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar_actionbar"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        <!-- android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"-->
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragment_drawer"
            android:name="com.package.name.navigationdrawer.NavigationDrawerFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"/>
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following behavior in parent layout:

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

I had almost similar issue in AppBarLayout which is under DrawerLayout. This might work.