# ListView doesn't work when i have DrawerLayout in Acivity Layout

Tags: android

Drawerlayout conflict with ListView in Activity Layout. but only ListView works fine and only DrawerLayout works fine too. problem is if they work together

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/diary_layout"
        android:background="@drawable/activebg">

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
            android:id="@+id/diary_list">
        </ListView>


        <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ListView android:id="@+id/navList"
                android:layout_width="240dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="start"
                android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
                android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
                android:dividerHeight="0dp"
                android:background="#111"/>
        </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>





    </RelativeLayout>
```

> in this situation when i have drawer layout listview doesn't work
>   (not click, not scroll). if remove

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ListView android:id="@+id/navList"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp"
            android:background="#111"/>
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

> this block listview works fine.  can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

```
Difference is that, in my example i use ListView(not ScrollView), there is solved this problem
```

[Android ScrollView not scrolling in Activity with Drawer Layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30754206/android-scrollview-not-scrolling-in-activity-with-drawer-layout)